# How can i resize bootstraps cards for a website using Django?

Tags: django, image-resizing, window-resize, bootstrap-cards

I'm trying to add some cards from bootstrap to a website to display images of the products with their prices and the option to add then to the cart but since the image in this card are being retrieved from another website, when I tried to load my page the images are too big and the cards don't resize automatically with the browser window so it shows one on top of another:

[image]

Comment: Welcome at SO. Best way to manipulate the frontend is by using CSS and/or Javascript generally spoken..

Comment: i don't how to use both language at the same time not even mentioning i only know python lol.

Answer (score 0):

you can add these properties to the image of the card.

```
.card_name img {
  height: 300px!important;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  object-fit: cover;
```

}